# Monte Carlo option pricing

Tags: option-pricing, monte-carlo, exotics

Can someone please confirm if I understood this correctly.

The Monte Carlo method for pricing path-dependent options essentially gives you a multitude of price processes, which you use to determine the payoff at the end. Because of the Central Limit Theorem, we know the average of of these discounted expected payoffs will look like a draw from a normal distribution with the true theoretical mean and an infinitesimal variance (given no. of simulations are large). We can then use the sample variance estimate to construct a confidence interval with a t-distribution, but given the number of simulations are large, we can just replace this with the normal.

I guess what I'm asking, is the validity and reliability of the Monte Carlo simulation a by-product of the Central Limit Theorem?